# filter dataset based on the selected values in ComboBox

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, c#-4.0, dataset

In my application I am trying to use `RowFilter` or `Select` methods of `DataSet` to show the values selected by the User in `ComboBox`. The `DataSet` has five columns hence my project has five `ComboBoxes` populated with same values of columns of `DataSet` respectively. Now I am trying to search the user selected values in the DataSet and populate in DataGridView. I have tried the below: (*not working*)

```
dgvMain.DataSource = null;
dgvMain.DataSource = dsMainDoctors.Tables[0].Select("Name = '" + cmbDoctorName.Text +"'");
```

**or**

```
dgvMain.DataSource = null;
dgvMain.DataSource = dsMainDoctors.Tables[0].DefaultView.RowFilter = "Name = '" + cmbDoctorName.Text + "'";
```

The first attempt is not showing anything but the second one is showing something like the below image instead of showing columns. Here I am trying to search with only one column value, but I need to search with three different columns of `DataSet` how to do that?

[image]

I know I am doing something wrong in my code. please suggest what should I do to correct my code. Please no linq because it is restricted by my head members. but all type of anwswers are welcome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try to assign the defaultview, after the filtering action, to the datasource

```
dgvMain.DataSource = null;
dsMainDoctors.Tables[0].DefaultView.RowFilter = "Name = '" + cmbDoctorName.Text + "'";
dgvMain.DataSource = dsMainDoctors.Tables[0].DefaultView;
```

Comment: Thank you for response. I know this but how to check for more than one column.

Comment: The RowFilter accepts an Expression as explained [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datacolumn.expression.aspx). You could merge your conditions like an SQL Where Clause. So you could write 'condition1 AND condition2 AND condition3'